# easeljs hit detection on scaled canvas sizes

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, createjs, easeljs

I'm new to the createJS suite of tools, so mind my ignorance on a few things. I am trying to get collision detection working on various items on my canvas. It works fine when the canvas is scaled to 865 x 1000px (default resolution), but when swapping to a responsive/scaled layout, hit detection stops working.

I am using Adobe Animate CC with the HTML5 Canvas doc type (Its a requirement for this project, wouldnt use it if i didnt have to), when the browser window shrinks down so does the canvas, changing its width and height properties from the original 865x1000 resolution.

I modified a function that I found on [a code pen](https://codepen.io/samualli/pen/xbVGpP) that would allow this to work on my project, while only passing in 1 object reference.

```
function intersect(obj1){

var objBounds1 = obj1.getBounds().clone();
var objBounds2;
switch (obj1.name) {
    case "snowBottom":
        objBounds2 = targetBottomRef.getBounds().clone(); 
        break;
    case "snowMiddle":
        objBounds2 = targetMiddleRef.getBounds().clone();
        break;
    case "snowTop":
    case "snowNose":
    case "snowHat":
    case "snowEyes":
        objBounds2 = targetTopRef.getBounds().clone(); 
        break;
}


var pt = obj1.globalToLocal(objBounds2.x, objBounds2.y);
console.log(pt);


var h1 = -(objBounds1.height / 2 + objBounds2.height);
var h2 = objBounds2.width / 2;
var w1 = -(objBounds1.width / 2 + objBounds2.width);
var w2 = objBounds2.width / 2;



if(pt.x > w2 || pt.x < w1) return false;
if(pt.y > h2 || pt.y < h1) return false;

return true;
}
```

I have 5 drag-able objects that intersect with 3 static placed "targets" object (targetBottomRef, targetMiddleRef & targetTopRef).

I have managed to trace down that the issue is coming the variable pt; changing when the window scales. h1, h2, w1 and w2 all stay the same, but pt changes.

Hit detection does in fact still work, but the actual "intersect" locations are completely off from the actual shape that I am testing the collision on. These locations change when I scale the window smaller and smaller. If the object I am trying to test collision with is placed directly in the center of the canvas, the point where it thinks it is is up and to the left of the actual object.

EDIT: Started logging some variables in the intersect function show.
I log; pt, objBounds2 and obj1.x & obj1.y.

```
PT: [Point (x=290.56847545219637 y=926.4528021055194)]
TARGET: [Rectangle (x=242 y=754.4 width=94 height=94)]
OBJ-CORDS: x=250.33591731266154 - y=759.7384123647649
```

As you can see OBJ-CORDS (The drag-able item), when visiting the location of the target (x=242 y=754.4), the pt still says its at x=290 y=926 in its local coordinates when it should be at x=0, y=0.

Comment: Can you supply a minimum current working example, use the code feature here. Ideally we need to see the code. I see the copepen link fine, but is that the code you're using now? Additionally, a quick scan of the issue suggests that the `globalToLocal()` function does not update its `global position coordinates` accurately if at all after a responsive change. Have a gander at this page if you haven't already: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/as2/reference/flashlite/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118ccf9c47f-7d07.html

Comment: Thanks for the response. Since I am using Adobe Animate, I cant really give a direct example of my own code. For the most part, the code I am using is the same as the one linked in the codepen. The issue I do believe is the globalToLocal call not changing as the canvas scales. [Here is a link](https://imgur.com/a/RXm0k) to an image of my items, green boxes are the targets, blue/purple are the drag-able objects. I forgot to mention, the bounds for my targets and dragable objects were set manually using "setBounds()".

Comment: @pokeybit forgot to tag you last comment. I remembered Adobe Animate just exports everything to an HTML and JS file. I have the code loaded into [a Code Pen](https://codepen.io/NicHens/pen/wPyxjK) so you can view it there. The code I wrote starts on line 149 of the JS file. Its really rough, as been testing out the functionality for the project I am working on.